# socket.io sync state across sockets

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm creating a board game where 2 players can play, and others can be spectators (viewers)
so, when a spectator joins, he gets the current state of the game, and from then on, he only gets the move each player has made (to save data obviously).

**My question is**: when the spectator first get the state of the game from the server, how can I make sure it is actually synced? I don't really know *when* he will get the state, and it might be a fraction of a second *before* something has changed, and then the Delta he gets for every move made won't make sense.

Should I use some kind of an internal? what would you suggest to make sure everything is synced?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your state is result of, and only of, user actions, you could store you state in a table like format with an auto-increment integer ID.

In the move event, you pass the new ID and the previous ID.  If the receiver's max ID is less than the previous ID, you know to ask server for the missing actions.

Comment: yes, I guess I could store the number of moves made, and compare it, and if it's not the same, then I would just pass the whole Array which represents the game, re-build it, and continue from there with the Deltas, as usual.

Comment: If you are using array to represent the state, you could imply store another 2 integers: currentID and previousID representing the index for the latest entry and the one before it.  This should allow you to pass the missing moves only instead of having to pass the entire array.  Obviously, this will not work if you ever remove items from this array.